# Canvas app works for multiple organziation

Tags: canvas

I created a simple canvas app and trying to set it up so that the app works for two organizations. On each organization, I have a page with that canvas app embedded within now. When I set up that CANVAS_CONSUMER_SECRET key for one organization from command line the canvas app on the other organization stoped working saying "We're sorry, but something went wrong" when I checked in Canvas App Previewer. If I tried to set the CANVAS_CONSUMER_SECRET key for the other one the same thing happens. I am not sure if I am doing wrong or misunderstanding the concept of canvas app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas app should exist only in one organization-- a developer edition. Once developed, you create a package and upload it. Then, install it in each other organization that wants to use the canvas app. In this way, your canvas app can work on multiple organizations using the same code.

Comment: Yep just gone through this process for my Apex UML Canvas app. I also packaged a localhost version of it, to make it easy to develop and test when running my local version of it in multiple orgs.